# Best way to handle views + taxonomy terms with just one linked node

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

For a Drupal 8 website with some different products I'm using taxonomies to organize the content. But I can't get it the way I want.

At first I organized the products like this:

- Term AA

  - Teaser node 1 --> Node 1
  - Teaser node 2 --> Node 2
  - Teaser node 3 --> Node 3
  - Teaser node 4 --> Node 4
- Term AB

  - Teaser node 5 -> Node 5
- Term AC

  - Teaser node 6 -> Node 6
- Term AD

  - Teaser node 7 -> Node 7

So from the menu I'll go to the term overview page and see the terms AA, AB, AC and AD. When I click on AA, I see different node teasers which lead me to the node if I click on one of them.
When I click on AB, I see just one node teaser. Same for AC and AD.

This is not really user friendly, because for AB. AC and AD the user goes to an overview with just one node teaser. And the term AB is actually the same as the Teaser node 5.

So then I tried to organize it like this:

- Term A

  - Term AA

    - Teaser node 1 --> Node 1
    - Teaser node 2 --> Node 2
    - Teaser node 3 --> Node 3
    - Teaser node 4 --> Node 4
  - Teaser node 5 -> Node 5
  - Teaser node 6 -> Node 6
  - Teaser node 7 -> Node 7

So then when I go to the overview page of term A, I would like to see a mixed page of terms and node teasers, which I think is not possible in views. (Or I just can't get it to work).

Another solution I'm thinking of is to somehow redirect the user, hitting terms with just one node attached to this node, right away. So looking at the first list of terms, that would mean that going to Term AB will lead me directly to Node 5. But .. also this I can't figure out how to do it.

So .. what should I do and how do I make this work? Is it possible with views or some kind of redirect, or should I do it totally different?

Comment: How are your taxonomy terms being applied, manually?  Will you ever see a second node under term AB?

Comment: As for solution 2, in 7 you would have done this check with hook_init.  Check the request url for relation to terms, query how many nodes are tagged, make a drupal_goto if needed.  But you are using drupal8? They have made this more difficult.  https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014

Comment: Yes, the tarxonomy terms are being applied manually. And there won't be another node under AB/AC/AD. Maybe in the future, but in that case I can do any configurations needed for that manually.


And .. yes, Drupal 8. Worse case is that I have to redirect every single node terms manually. I rather not, but if that is the best solution, then .. so be it.

Comment: If you are having to do it manually anyway, why not go for a different menu system instead of taxonomy?

Comment: Thanks DeveloperWeeks. Indeed if I had to start over I would have chosen that path, not using taxonomy. But since that would have cost me a lot more time at this stage, I've chosen to go with the redirects, using https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect.
Not a very pretty solution, but the best and fastest one I think.